# Probability density function, cumulative distribution functions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A quick question with regards to cumulative distribution function.

To find the probability density function of $X$ do you:

(1) $Pr(x\ <\ X\ <\ x+h)\ =\ F_x(x+h)\ -\ F_x(x)\ =\ h\frac{dF_x(x)}{dx}$

or

(2) $Pr(a\ \leq\ X\ \leq\ b)\ =\ \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$

Im getting confused as many sites say option 2, but I've been given the option 1.

Or are they just the same thing and im missing the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small $h$, under appropriate continuity conditions, the first is a good *approximation*. The second is fully correct.

The first can be a useful way of thinking: if $f_X(x)$ is the **density** function of $X$, then $\Pr(x\lt X \lt x+h)\approx hf_X(x)$. In general, $F_X(x)$ has a clear probabilistic meaning, It is harder to visualize $f_X(x)$ probabilistically.